# Compiling nginx with nginx-gridfs, getting mongo-c-driver errors during make

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-11.04, nginx

I'm attempting to compile nginx (version 1.0.11) with gridfs support (nginx-gridfs version 0.8) on Ubuntu 11.10 (gcc version 4.6) using the nginx module here:

```
https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs
```

The installation instructions described there are simple:

```
* Clone the nginx-gridfs repository (`git clone https://github.com/mdirolf/nginx-gridfs`)
* Check out the mongo-c-driver submodule (`git submodule init` then `git submodule update`)
* Download and unpack the nginx source (from `http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.0.11.tar.gz`)
* Run `./configure` with `--add-module=/path/to/nginx-gridfs/repository`
* `make` and `sudo make install`
```

These steps worked fine for me last time I set up nginx-gridfs on a machine (about four months ago on Ubuntu 10.04, with gcc 4.5 and nginx version 1.0.5), but now (on a fresh Ubuntu install) I'm getting an error. The `./configure` is working fine, but `make` fails with:

```
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c: In function 'mongo_count':
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:939:5: error: missing initializer [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:939:5: error: (near initialization for 'out.dataSize') [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c: In function 'mongo_simple_int_command':
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:981:5: error: missing initializer [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:981:5: error: (near initialization for 'out.dataSize') [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c: In function 'mongo_simple_str_command':
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:1013:5: error: missing initializer [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:1013:5: error: (near initialization for 'out.dataSize') [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c: In function 'mongo_cmd_get_error_helper':
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:1055:5: error: missing initializer [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:1055:5: error: (near initialization for 'out.dataSize') [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c: In function 'mongo_cmd_ismaster':
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:1098:5: error: missing initializer [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
/path/to/nginx-gridfs/mongo-c-driver/src/mongo.c:1098:5: error: (near initialization for 'out.dataSize') [-Werror=missing-field-initializers]
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
make[1]: *** [objs/addon/src/mongo.o] Error 1
```

Any idea why this would fail?

The `cc1: all warnings being treated as errors` leads me to believe that I may be able to add `-Wno-error` to `CFLAGS` to tell it not treat warnings as errors to avoid this issue. But I'm worried that treat-warnings-as-errors is enabled here for a reason, and that turning it off would only make the compilation successful on the surface, but not actually work.

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Adding `--with-cc-opt=-Wno-error` did allow the make to complete successfully. I will report back if this results in any problems.

Comment: Having this same issue. Please do report!

Comment: So far, no problems using the solution in my comment.

Comment: `--with-cc-opt=-Wno-missing-field-initializers` is a bit more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using your ignore warnings methods made the compilation work but I would actually get failure to connect to the database with user/password errors in use. What worked for me was a combination of building mongo from scratch to supply nginx build with newer libs: http://pastebin.com/tMsL2eC9

But this wasnt actually enough. I also had to specifically check out mongo c driver v0.3.1 in the submodule of nginx-gridfs. So that is, v0.8 of nginx gridfs. V0.3.1 mongo c driver, and the fresh mongo build being references from the env specified in that link. Then I built nginx 1.0.11 with no errors and it worked.